# try to save in internal bitmap picture

Tags: java, android, android-studio

the app is when the member click the btn camera is open and take pic and the see it in the image view. and when he close the app the picture need to save in the internal storage. 
the problem is when i click in the btn and click V after i take photo the app is crash/

```
package com.e.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

global variables:

```
    final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;
    ImageView imageview;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

this is the load image:

```
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("pictures");
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            fis.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        imageview = findViewById(R.id.image_result);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

this is the save:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("pictures",MODE_PRIVATE);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,fos);
            fos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ` the problem is when i click in the btn and click V after i take photo the app is crash`? what is `V`? Also, can you please share crash log from logcat? It will help finding the cause.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.e.test/com.e.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded

Comment: And i mean after i take the a photo  the app is crash

Comment: can you share the full activity code

Comment: You see it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` occurs because your `bitmap` instance is null. Not sure how you are using this code but you can add a null check to ensure that the `bitmap` is not null evrytime you perform operations on it (e.g compressing it). Then your app will not crash. like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try {
        if(bitmap != null){
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("pictures",MODE_PRIVATE);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,fos);
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: But if i do this so its not enter the if statement because the bitmap is null how i do that the bitmap not be null? Maybe declare bitmap = " ";      or something??

Comment: You cannot do this: `bitmap = " "`. You cannot fully assure that Bitmap not be null. You have to check for nullability.